Replacing multiple strings in dataframe using dplyr
I have a dataset with over 6000 observations and over 300 different variables. Some of these variables are character-variables with strings. Some of strings contain swearwords which I want to replace with the expression "[incivility]" or misspellings.
Here is an example data-frame:
df <- data.frame(
id = 1:6,
date = seq.Date(as.Date("2024-12-01"), as.Date("2024-12-06"), "day"),
group = rep(LETTERS[1:2], 3),
tex1 = c("First strings", "second strings", "third strings", "fourth string",
         "fift strings", "sixth strigs"),
text2 = c("first example", "second example", "third example", "forth example",
          "fift  example", "sixth example")
)

And here is a dataframe containing the original strings and the replacement strings:
df_replace <- data.frame(
    original = c("first", "second", "example", "fift", "third", "fourth"),
    replacement = c("[incivility]", "[incivility]", "[incivility]", "fifth", "third", "fourth")
)

With the help of Iroha and the answers to this question (How to use across and mutate across an entire dataset that has multiple column types?), I was able to solve the problem with the following code:
df_replace <- df_replace |> na.omit()

df |> mutate(across(where(is.character),
                           \(x) stringr::str_replace_all(x, tibble::deframe(df_replace))))
                

As you can see, I also had to remove all NAs in the replacement dataset (there are no NAs in this example, but there were some in my original replacement dataset. With NAs in it, the script did not work. But now, it ran smoothly and did what I wanted it to do. Thank you!!!

mutate(across(is.character, …))  from the tidyverse will be your friend.

thank you, I came a step closer to the solution, but I am still not there

Try df |> mutate(across(where(is.character), \(x) stringr::str_replace_all(x, tibble::deframe(df_replace)))).

Something like this should give you what you want:
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  mutate(
    across(
      where(is.character),
      \(x) str_replace_all(
        x,
        "first|second|example|third|fift|fourth|third",
        "[incivility]"
      ),
      .names = "{.col}_replacement"
    )
  )

  id       date group           tex1          text2 group_replacement     tex1_replacement          text2_replacement
1  1 2024-12-01     A  First strings  first example                 A        First strings  [incivility] [incivility]
2  2 2024-12-02     B second strings second example                 B [incivility] strings  [incivility] [incivility]
3  3 2024-12-03     A  third strings  third example                 A [incivility] strings  [incivility] [incivility]
4  4 2024-12-04     B  fourth string  forth example                 B  [incivility] string         forth [incivility]
5  5 2024-12-05     A   fift strings  fift  example                 A [incivility] strings [incivility]  [incivility]
6  6 2024-12-06     B   sixth strigs  sixth example                 B         sixth strigs         sixth [incivility]

You can play around with the regex string (and the regex settings) and the .names parameter if this doesn't exactly match your needs.

... but I still feel the original question is a duplicate.
